# Question on system of linear equations.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, complex-numbers, systems-of-equations, matrix-rank

[Note] the below question is Multiple choice question,  that is it may have more than one correct options.

Question: let $A$ be a $3×4$ matrix with integer entries and $b$ is a $3×1$ matrix with integer entries. Suppose that the system $Ax=b$ has complex solution then, which of following are true

(a) $Ax =b$ has an integer solution

(b) $Ax =b$ has rational solution.

(c) the set of real solution to $Ax=0$ has basis consisting of rational solution.

(d) if $b≠0$ then $A$ has positive rank.

The above question was asked in "Csir- Net Mathematics examination (Dec-2014) India"

I just know that, system $Ax = b$  has solution if $rank(A) = rank(A|b)$.
Please help me. I am unable to solve it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(a) is false. Suppose that the entries of $b$ are all equal to $1$ and that the entries of $A$ are even numbers. Then no integer solution can exist.

(b) and (c) is true. Just use row reduction (and the fact that the entries of $A$ are integers) to prove it.

(d) is also true. This is so because if $Ax=b$ has a solution, then $A$ cannot be the null matrix (because $b\neq0$) and therefore its rank is at least $1$.

Comment: Thanks Sir ,but in key they had provided the answer (b), (c) & (d).

Comment: @AkashPatalwanshi Under the hypothesis that you provided, my answer is correct. Perhaps that you forgot to mention that the entries of $b$ are integer too.

Comment: Yes sir. I forgot that and just edited it.

Comment: Sir. Yes $b$ has integer entries then how option (b) is correct?

Comment: @AkashPatalwanshi I've edited my answer. Please, the next time you post a question here, try to post all hypothesis.

Comment: Sorry for that sir. Mistakenly I forgot it and thanks for your help. Got it.